# Xdebug does not work in PhpStorm when I run Drupal site on Docksal

Tags: docker, drupal, phpstorm, xdebug, docksal

I need Xdebug to keep track of incoming data, where it goes, etc.
Since I run(raise up) the Drupal site using docksal, I set it up according to the instructions https://docs.docksal.io/tools/xdebug/#phpstorm

1. I wrote the command:
   `fin config set --env=local XDEBUG_ENABLED=1`

And in the file docksal-local.env changed to:
`XDEBUG_ENABLED="1"`

2. I wrote the command:
   `fin project start`
3. I checked xdebug:
   `fin exec php-v | grep -i xdebug`

And received:
`with Xdebug v3.0.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans`

4. In the index.php file, I put a breakpoint on some line
5. I clicked the **Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections** button
6. I went to the site page in the browser, updated it and returned to PhpStorm

But nothing happened. What do I need to do to make Xdebug work?

Comment: Have you read the full documentation? It's at https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug

Comment: Have you done any settings changes in php storm to listen to a remote server and port for xdebug? I have not myself used PhpStorm but you will need to configure it to listen to the right ip and port. I suspect standard settings are for localhost and standard port

Comment: You need to start with showing your actual live Xdebug config. It's quite possible that your Xdebug is not configured at all (e.g. wrong IP:port used, not in debug mode etc)... Get some PHP file and place `xdebug_info();` there, call such a page via browser and post the whole output here (may need couple of screenshots as it's a bit tall).

Comment: @Virre No, I didn't change any settings in PhpStorm. Thanks, I'll see

Comment: Also posted on https://forums.docker.com/t/xdebug-does-not-work-in-phpstorm-when-i-run-drupal-site-on-docksal/122600

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For xdebug 3 add environment variables for cli:

```
  cli:
    environment:
      - "XDEBUG_CONFIG=client_host=${DOCKSAL_HOST_IP} client_port=9000"
      - "XDEBUG_MODE=debug"
```

See https://github.com/docksal/docksal/issues/1450#issuecomment-812889179

Comment: Thanks, they really need to update their web docs on this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, as indicated @Hamrant it works, it is only necessary to keep in mind to restart the Docksal service so that it takes the changes.